# Stop child threads started by `performSelector` on `viewDidDisappear`

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading

To begin, I realise I may be causing this problem by addressing a previous problem incorrectly...

In a `ViewController` main thread I am starting a background thread to get updated data from a server using:

```
[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(sampleTask:) withObject:@"CMD" ];
```

This process can take 15-30 seconds so in the main thread I display a local cache of the data from a SQLite database (populated from a previous request to the server the last time the view was opened) and reload the table once the sync with the server is finished.

If the user navigates back out of this view before the sync with the server is finished, the background thread keeps running until it is done. This itself isn't a problem, until the user changes their mind and goes back into this view again. If the timing is right, there's two background threads trying to sync data with the server. If the user does this a few times, the thread count can build up. Eventually the app will collapse, if not cause other problems on the device.

- Is there a way to stop the created threads on a trigger like `viewDidDisappear`?
- Or should I be writing a lock to a shared resource (e.g. `NSUserDefaults`) to prevent a new background thread from being started?
- Or -- like I mentioned in the first line -- do I have a bad approach to the issue of updating the local cache that is just causing further problems like this one?

Comment: That line of code does not start a background thread. It is run on the same thread it was called from, just not until the delay has expired.

Comment: Sorry, wrong example, performSelectorInBackground was what I meant. Still experiencing similar behaviour with performSelector though. If performSelector behaves that way, how am I seeing the "sampleTask" still running after viewDidDisappear has ran. 

I am using model segues between the views. When is the ViewController destroyed that runs performSelector? Is that the part I am missing?

Comment: Edited OP to use a background thread rather than current thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use simple bool valued semaphore which shows that some sync task is performing. So before performing the next similar task you should check that semaphore.
If you recreate your viewcontroller each time you need static class variable common for all instances of your view controller.

Comment: It's messy, but only solution I can see at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

`performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` does not create a separate thread.

To quote part of the docs on that method:

> Invokes a method of the receiver **on the current thread** using the
>   default mode after a delay

It uses a timer to trigger your selector after a delay. As such it is subject to the same accuracy limitations as NSTimer.  (The method `performSelectorInBackground:withObject:` **does** submit your selector on a background thread.)

But back to your question.

You can use the method

```
cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:selector:object:
```

To cancel a pending call to `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:`

Comment: That doesn't answer my question exactly... 

cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget stops the call only if its still within the time bracket of afterDelay. It is useful to know though, it can prevent the selector from executing if it hasn't started already. 

But the problem will still exist that selector "sampleTask" can still be running when the view is closed and reopened (if the user is fast enough).

Comment: Well, no. Since the performSelector:withObject:afterDelay: does not start the task on a different thread, the method will be running on the main thread. Thus the user won't be able to do anything until the method has completed.